# Vim syntax file not matching with \zs

Tags: regex, vim, syntax, f#

I am trying to obtain some effeciency improvements by changing this line in my fsharp syntax file (from [this](https://github.com/fsharp/vim-fsharp) plugin) from:

```
syn match    fsharpModule     "\%(\<open\s\+\)\@<=[a-zA-Z.]\+"
```

to

```
syn match    fsharpModule     "\%(\<open\s\+\)\zs[a-zA-Z.]\+"
```

since the docs on the "\@<=" construct states that:

> For speed it's often much better to avoid this multi.  Try using "\zs" instead |/\zs|.

However, this doesn't work and there is no highligting for

```
open SomeModule
```

How can this be? Doing a regular search in vim (with /) highligts the 'SomeModule' both when using the first and the second match pattern.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the syntax containment and because another syntax group exists for the `open` keyword that you're trying to assert.

Within syntax highlighting, `\zs` only affects the result (what Vim will highlight with the syntax group); the whole pattern (i.e. including the text before the `\zs`) is treated as the match when it comes to relationships with other syntax groups. (This implementation detail is not explicitly documented in the help.) The *positive lookbehind assertion* (`\%(...\)\@<=`), by contrast, is neither included in the result nor the actual match. That explains the difference in behavior that you see. (It has nothing to do with the optional grouping, as @rmunn suspected, nor with multiple lines as per @Sergio's answer, as `\s\+` will not allow a linebreak in between.)

I think ease of implementation is more important here, so it should be fine to use `\@<=`, even though the help recommends `\zs`. If you're willing to completely restructure the syntax script, this could be solved with something along these lines, assuming there's a `syntax keyword fsharpOpen open` somewhere:

```
syntax keyword fsharpOpen nextgroup=fsharpModule skipwhite open
syntax match fsharpModule "[a-zA-Z.]\+" contained
```

Answer (score 2):

In the [Vim docs for the `\@<=` construct](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@%3C=), the example of using `\zs` omits the parentheses that had been present in the equivalent pattern match using `\@<=`. I'm just guessing, but what happens if you try the following syntax match?

```
syn match    fsharpModule     "\<open\s\+\zs[a-zA-Z.]\+"
```

Comment: Nope, that still don't work. I've tried with different versions of the pattern, all of which i got working when doing search in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

As described in `:help syn-mult-line`, `\zs` has a few restrictions in a syntax command:

> When using a start pattern with an offset, the start of the match is       not allowed to start in a following line.  The highlighting can start   in a following line though.  Using the "\zs" item also requires that       the start of the match doesn't move to another line.

so very likely `@<=` is is the best possible solution.