# Why does this regular expression not work in Vim syntax highlighting?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, vim, syntax-highlighting

I am attempting to create my own Python syntax highlighting file for Vim.

I'm trying to highlight the class inheritance object and the regex I've created
works in various regex testers, but doesn;t work in Vim. I've read that Vim's regex is close to Perl style
so that is what I've been using.

I'm trying to highlight the word 'Subscribers' in the following text:

```
class Divisions(Subscribers):
```

The regex I've composed is:

```
(?!:class\s\w+)(?<=\()\w+(?=\):)
```

I'll be honest here, I stumbled into this while I was struggling to make a negative lookbehind work with quantifiers,
which I now understand isn't possible. I was experimenting with the non-capturing group (?:class\s\w+) and accidentally
inserted the exclamation mark which 'magically' solved the problem. At least in the multiple regex testers I was using.

Just for clarity, then follows a look behind (?<=() to caputre but not include the '('
and then a look ahead after the word (?=):) to capture but not include the closing '):'

I've added it to my Vim syntax file as:

```
syn match pythonClassInherit "(?!:class\s\w+)(?<=\()\w+(?=\):)"
```

Is this a valid regular expression in Vim? If not, can anybody offer a working solution for Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I realized that I've had overcomplicated the issue; you just need a right Vim regex. Try

```
syntax match pythonClassInherit "\%(class\s\+\h\w*\s*(\s*\)\@<=\h\w*\%(\s*):\)\@="
highlight link pythonClassInherit pythonImport
```

Then you'll see the result:

[image: Highlighting example]

You may replace `pythonImport` by another predefined highlight group.

For highlighting, I found https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/ (highlighting starts from Chap. 45) helpful. As for regex, romainl's suggestion is awesome.

---

My first attempt was to use regex `\zs`. This, unlike `\@<=`, requires that the syntax group cover the part that comes before `\zs`, which cannot be satisfied because some other groups have already occupied that part. This led me a complicated solution, by overriding the default highlight groups to include a new group (for `Subscribers`). But it turns out we really don't have to.

If interested, see [Vim syntax file not matching with \zs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323753/vim-syntax-file-not-matching-with-zs).

Comment: I had just found the documentation on zoom anchors when you replied and was about to go down that road. This is exactly what I needed to understand, about groupings. Thanks for the explanation and the link to the docs! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Online regular expression playgrounds don't support Vim's syntax so using them is pointless, here.

See [vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com/) for an overview, `:help usr_27` for a gentle tutorial, `:help pattern` for the definitive reference, and `:help perl-patterns` for the differences between the Vim syntax and the Perl syntax.

Comment: I didn't know we could access the reference within Vim. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Much appreciated!